# What kind of Houses would a sapient Albatross build

Tags: avian

I am wondering what kind of house would a Sapient Albatross build. I did a little researth and found out that they build very simple nests maid out of mud feathers or rocks. but my sapient race would probably build quite tall and defensive homes to defend themselves from animals like foxs or cats.They have metalurgy and do fish farming so they can be considered medievel.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Presumably some place where lost mariners won't be able to shoot them.

Comment: They would not (_I_ don't think) be able to manipulate the equipment for metallurgy, and they would need to have near-human level IQ in order to recognize metal as a superior building material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A albatross might have trouble not only manipulating objects with its wings, and the shear size of its wingspan compared to other birds would make nesting in a thicket or canopy impractical. However on probably some trees with wide branches leading of like maritime pine they could construct nests and houses there. Maybe using the feet and beak as manipulators, they could be made out of sticks and stones, weaved together with spiders webs. Some species of bird use spiders webs to make their nest, and in colder  and moist climates using mud isn't always the best idea. The homes might be smallish since it would be substantially harder to build a equivalent structure for them. On most islands however, where the alabtross species thrives there are no predation or trees, so maybe they could extend and pillage the homes and burrows of smaller sea birds . This would protect them from wind chill and wheather, and also open up the option for more elaborate homes, vast labyrinth mazes.